# Are there any players (or other programs) intended for transcription?

Tags: sound, text, multimedia, audio-recording, playback

I mean players that include features related to listening to recorded talking for the purpose of putting that into text.

One elementary feature would be a somewhat refined way of play/stopping, jumping back and forward with short-keys.

More advanced features would be to alter various aspects of the sound in order to understand more complex or badly recorded sounds of voices.

(I wouldn't mind an answer indicating a sound-to-text program that would automate all that transcription work as well :))

Answer (score 1):

Try [TranscriberAG](http://transag.sourceforge.net/index.php?content=install), unfortunately, it needs compiling manually, though.