# Audio to subtitle in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, subtitle

Is there any free tool available that can generate .srt subtitle file from an audio for 16.04 ? I am aware of uploading to YouTube, but there are a few videos I do not want to upload to a public domain, but need subtitles for offline use.

PS: I am looking to use in the English language. Both audio and subs

Any help possible ?

Comment: I heard about "speech-to-text" (and text-to-speech) software but never about one that could generate (time coded) subtitles.

Comment: @MichaelBay , YouTube allows exporting .srt out of our own uploaded video. Any good speech to text available then ?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot export an .srt from a YT video if no subtitles were uploaded. The closed captions that youtube generates automatically are in a different format (some html or mpeg/dash format) and the quality can vary greatly. I thought that subtitles of the [Chaos Communication Congress](https://c3subtitles.de/) were already fully automated  so that there must be a software package available to download, but that doesn't appear to be the case. The only thing I can offer for now are the following links: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/34740/13644 https://askubuntu.com/q/214722/40581

Comment: @LiveWireBT we can export subtitles out of YouTube       press the Edit button to begin adjusting them. On the left side, you'll see the transcription that YouTube automatically generated. You can type over any of the incorrect subtitles to correct them. Use the embedded video player to work your way through the video and intervene as needed. Click Publish Edits when you're finished to save the corrected subtitles.

To export and download a subtitle file, click the Actions dropdown and select the file type you need. SRT is a widely supported format (including Facebook video).